# SummarySE (Rmisc package) to produce a barplot with error bars (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I am attempting to build a barplot with error bars using the `ggplot2` package showing 13 predictor variables on the x axis (the data frame `behaviours` can be found below). The predictors will ideally be grouped by the response variable (`family`) containing two levels (G8 and V4), represented by two coloured bars per predictor plus a key. I have tried to follow an example from the Cookbook for R (see below). I would like to summarise the data using the function `summarySE` from the `Rmisc` package to calculate the standard deviation, standard error of the mean, and a (default 95%) confidence interval, however, my code shows warning messages and returns NA's. I am unsure what the correct syntax is for the function `summarySE()`. How can I implement the R Cookbook example for my data?

My Code using the function `summarySE':

```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(Rmisc) 

   # (1) First Try - Equation 1

   summary.behaviours <- summarySE(behaviours, 
                                   measurevar="Family", 
                                   groupvars=c("Swimming", 
                                               "Not.Swimming",
                                               "Running", 
                                               "Not.Running",
                                               "Fighting",
                                               "Not.Fighting",
                                               "Resting",
                                               "Not.Resting",
                                               "Hunting",
                                               "Not.Hunting",
                                               "Grooming",
                                               "Not.Grooming",
                                               "Other"),
                                                na.rm = TRUE)
   # (2) Second Try - Equation 2

   summary.behaviours <- summarySE(behaviours,    
                                      measurevar =  c("Swimming", 
                                                      "Not.Swimming",
                                                      "Running", 
                                                      "Not.Running",
                                                      "Fighting",
                                                      "Not.Fighting",
                                                      "Resting",
                                                      "Not.Resting",
                                                      "Hunting",
                                                      "Not.Hunting",
                                                      "Grooming",
                                                      "Not.Grooming",
                                                      "Other"),
                                             groupvar="Family",
                                                      na.rm = TRUE)
```

## Warning messages

Warning messages for Equation (1)

```
1: In mean.default(xx[, col], na.rm = na.rm) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(xx[, col], na.rm = na.rm) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

and many more warnings of the same kind.

Error messages for equation (2):

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(xx, , col) : undefined columns selected
```

## Example code from the Cookbook for R

Reference: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

summarySE provides the standard deviation, standard error of the mean,    and a (default 95%) confidence interval

```
  tgc <- summarySE(tg, measurevar="len", groupvars=c("supp","dose"))
  tgc

  #>   supp dose  N   len       sd        se       ci
  #> 1   OJ  0.5 10 13.23 4.459709 1.4102837 3.190283
  #> 2   OJ  1.0 10 22.70 3.910953 1.2367520 2.797727
  #> 3   OJ  2.0 10 26.06 2.655058 0.8396031 1.899314
  #> 4   VC  0.5 10  7.98 2.746634 0.8685620 1.964824
  #> 5   VC  1.0 10 16.77 2.515309 0.7954104 1.799343
  #> 6   VC  2.0 10 26.14 4.797731 1.5171757 3.432090

  # Use dose as a factor rather than numeric

  tgc2 <- tgc
  tgc2$dose <- factor(tgc2$dose)

  # Error bars represent standard error of the mean

  ggplot(tgc2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=len-se, ymax=len+se),
              width=.2,               # Width of the error bars
              position=position_dodge(.9))


  # Use 95% confidence intervals instead of SEM

    ggplot(tgc2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=supp)) + 
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=len-ci, ymax=len+ci),
              width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
              position=position_dodge(.9))
```

## My data

```
behaviours <- structure(list(Family = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("G8", "v4"), class =     "factor"), 
Swimming = c(-0.4805568, 0.12600625, 0.06823834, 0.67480139, 
0.64591744, 0.21265812, -0.01841352, 0.12600625, -0.2206012, 
0.27042603, 0.03935439, -0.45167284, -0.04729748, -0.10506539, 
0.0971223, -0.07618143, 0.29930998, 0.01047043, -0.24948516, 
-0.04729748, -0.01841352, -0.19171725, -0.4805568, 0.01047043, 
-0.42278889, -0.45167284, -0.30725307, 0.24154207, 1.45466817, 
-0.01841352, 0.38596185, 0.15489021, -0.04729748, 0.27042603, 
-0.07618143, -0.10506539, -0.01841352, 0.01047043, 0.06823834, 
-0.16283329, -0.01841352, -0.39390493, -0.04729748, 0.01047043, 
0.01047043, 0.06823834, -0.04729748, -0.2206012, -0.16283329, 
-0.07618143, -0.2206012, -0.19171725, -0.16283329, -0.2206012, 
-0.13394934, -0.27836911, -0.04729748, 0.01047043, 0.12600625, 
0.06823834, 0.06823834, 0.32819394, 0.32819394, -0.27836911, 
0.18377416, 0.55926557, -0.19171725, -0.19171725, 0.01047043, 
-0.19171725, -0.01841352, -0.07618143, -0.13394934, -0.39390493, 
-0.04729748, -0.27836911, 0.70368535, 0.29930998, -0.13394934, 
0.21265812), Not.Swimming = c(-0.0862927, -0.074481895, -0.056765686, 
-0.050860283, -0.050860283, -0.068576492, -0.068576492, 0.05543697, 
0.114491, -0.021333268, -0.04495488, 0.008193747, -0.056765686, 
0.008193747, 0.037720761, 0.01409915, 0.108585597, -0.074481895, 
0.002288344, 0.049531567, 0.043626164, 0.049531567, 0.020004552, 
0.008193747, 0.025909955, 0.031815358, 0.049531567, -0.039049477, 
-0.003617059, 0.002288344, 0.084963985, -0.080387298, 0.067247776, 
0.031815358, 0.037720761, 0.025909955, 0.126301805, 0.031815358, 
0.037720761, -0.050860283, -0.039049477, -0.003617059, 0.008193747, 
-0.039049477, -0.003617059, 0.008193747, 0.01409915, -0.015427865, 
0.020004552, 0.031815358, 0.020004552, -0.033144074, -0.039049477, 
-0.009522462, -0.003617059, -0.04495488, -0.050860283, -0.04495488, 
-0.068576492, -0.033144074, -0.027238671, -0.068576492, 0.01409915, 
0.002288344, 0.025909955, -0.009522462, -0.009522462, 0.025909955, 
0.15582882, 0.002288344, -0.04495488, -0.015427865, 0.008193747, 
0.037720761, 0.008193747, -0.015427865, -0.056765686, 0.079058582, 
-0.056765686, 0.025909955), Running = c(-0.157157188, 0.057316151, 
0.064711783, 0.153459372, 0.072107416, 0.057316151, -0.053618335, 
0.012942357, -0.03882707, 0.049920519, 0.012942357, -0.075805232, 
0.035129254, -0.046222702, 0.109085578, -0.03882707, 0.057316151, 
0.020337989, 0.035129254, 0.057316151, 0.005546724, -0.016640173, 
-0.142365923, 0.220020063, -0.149761556, -0.134970291, 0.042524886, 
0.072107416, 0.064711783, 0.020337989, 0.049920519, 0.020337989, 
0.138668107, 0.049920519, 0.020337989, -0.083200864, -0.024035805, 
-0.016640173, -0.03882707, -0.03882707, 0.005546724, -0.090596497, 
-0.00924454, -0.016640173, -0.075805232, -0.090596497, 0.012942357, 
-0.075805232, -0.061013967, -0.03882707, -0.112783394, -0.068409599, 
-0.090596497, -0.053618335, -0.075805232, -0.090596497, 0.064711783, 
0.012942357, 0.042524886, -0.061013967, -0.061013967, 0.064711783, 
0.175646269, -0.068409599, 0.027733621, 0.042524886, -0.03882707, 
-0.00924454, 0.027733621, -0.031431438, -0.046222702, -0.031431438, 
-0.068409599, -0.120179026, 0.035129254, -0.061013967, 0.39751524, 
0.138668107, 0.020337989, 0.035129254), Not.Running = c(-0.438809944, 
-0.539013927, -0.539013927, -0.539013927, -0.472211271, -0.071395338, 
-0.071395338, 0.296019267, 0.563229889, -0.03799401, 0.195815284, 
-0.171599321, -0.305204632, 0.062209973, -0.104796666, 0.095611301, 
    0.028808645, -0.071395338, 0.329420595, 0.296019267, -0.171599321, 
    -0.071395338, 0.596631217, 0.062209973, 0.028808645, -0.138197994, 
    0.095611301, -0.104796666, 0.296019267, 0.028808645, -0.03799401, 
    -0.33860596, 0.129012629, 0.195815284, -0.03799401, 0.396223251, 
    0.362821923, -0.138197994, 0.26261794, -0.405408616, -0.205000649, 
    0.129012629, 0.195815284, -0.205000649, -0.004592683, -0.205000649, 
    -0.071395338, -0.171599321, -0.104796666, -0.138197994, -0.104796666, 
    -0.071395338, -0.104796666, -0.03799401, -0.004592683, -0.238401977, 
    0.028808645, -0.305204632, -0.305204632, -0.271803305, -0.03799401, 
    -0.372007288, 0.095611301, 0.195815284, 0.162413956, 0.229216612, 
    0.229216612, 0.396223251, 0.630032545, 0.463025906, 0.496427234, 
    0.062209973, -0.071395338, 0.229216612, -0.071395338, -0.071395338, 
    -0.205000649, 0.229216612, -0.305204632, 0.396223251), Fighting = c(-0.67708172, 
    -0.58224128, -0.11436177, -0.34830152, -0.84568695, -0.32933343, 
    0.35984044, -0.3251183, 1.51478626, 0.11114773, 0.27975296, 
    -0.89626852, 0.12379312, 0.66965255, 1.56536783, 0.56427428, 
    -0.71291033, -0.75927677, -0.75295407, -1.00164679, -1.03958296, 
    0.82139726, -1.07541157, -1.0311527, -0.98900139, -1.06908888, 
    -1.20186549, 0.58324237, -0.9700333, 0.22917139, 0.41042201, 
    -1.11545531, -0.19023412, 0.25446217, -0.05324237, 0.09007207, 
    1.21129685, 0.62539368, 1.32932051, 0.40199175, 0.44625062, 
    0.60221046, 0.33665722, -0.63493041, -0.282967, -0.32722587, 
    -0.11646933, -0.10171637, 0.13643851, -0.57802615, 0.05002833, 
    -0.1607282, -0.29139726, 0.13222338, -0.41152848, 0.68229794, 
    -0.24292325, -0.11646933, -0.21341734, -0.24292325, -0.24292325, 
    0.09007207, -0.34197883, -0.30825778, -0.08696342, -0.8119659, 
    0.49683219, -0.13754498, -0.4831857, 0.39988418, 0.90148474, 
    0.28396809, 1.05322945, 1.24923303, 0.47154141, 1.27873894, 
    0.05002833, 1.54218461, 0.74763247, 0.11747042), Not.Fighting = c(-0.097624192, 
    -0.160103675, -0.092996082, -0.234153433, -0.136963126, -0.15778962, 
    -0.15778962, -0.023574435, 0.00188017, -0.224897213, -0.109194467, 
    -0.069855533, -0.123078796, -0.111508522, -0.143905291, -0.099938247, 
    -0.118450687, 1.519900201, 0.177748344, 0.108326696, 0.652129604, 
    0.638245274, -0.072169588, 0.087500202, -0.18093017, -0.146219346, 
    -0.049029039, -0.125392851, -0.134649071, -0.060599313, -0.086053918, 
    -0.197128554, -0.083739863, -0.092996082, 0.844196163, 0.055103433, 
    1.971140911, -0.111508522, -0.224897213, -0.187872334, -0.160103675, 
    -0.194814499, -0.053657149, -0.206384774, 0.108326696, -0.164731785, 
    0.187004564, 0.025020719, 0.057417488, 0.434608441, 0.057417488, 
    0.073615872, -0.035144709, -0.051343094, -0.134649071, -0.185558279, 
    0.013450444, -0.134649071, -0.215640993, -0.185558279, -0.005061995, 
    -0.238781543, -0.099938247, -0.16704584, -0.208698829, 0.048161268, 
    0.048161268, -0.037458764, 0.16154996, 0.031962884, -0.102252302, 
    -0.123078796, -0.139277181, -0.208698829, -0.118450687, -0.072169588, 
    -0.044400929, -0.030516599, -0.132335016, -0.037458764), 
    Resting = c(0.01081204879, -0.03398160805, 0.057108797, -0.04063432116, 
    -0.13084281035, -0.02997847693, 0.12732080268, -0.1028170581, 
    0.08155320398, -0.17932134171, -0.14338902206, -0.02058415581, 
    -0.11528274705, -0.11764091337, 0.04389156236, 0.01399844913, 
    -0.05755560242, 0.04711630687, 0.0158428036, 0.093485909, 
    0.09677967302, 0.02053612974, -0.03608286844, 0.07805238146, 
    -9.686695e-05, -0.02285413055, -0.00424187149, 0.01446241356, 
    0.03187450017, 0.11323315542, -0.01171898422, -0.06499053655, 
    -0.07758659568, -0.07399758157, -0.11503350996, 0.02167111711, 
    0.01904454162, 0.05768779393, 0.05555202379, -0.01031175326, 
    -0.00458313459, 0.17430774591, 0.00481502094, -0.00928412956, 
    0.09047589183, 0.08917985896, -0.05671203072, -0.05333390954, 
    0.08541446168, 0.10140397965, -0.02509342995, -0.0369877908, 
    0.04609635201, 0.06524159499, 0.0845977309, -0.03239032508, 
    -0.03208740616, 0.06264952925, 0.05241547086, -0.03437271856, 
    -0.03437271856, -0.06747523863, -0.01270059491, 0.10014629095, 
    -0.02872845706, -0.00950652573, 0.04867308008, 0.02486518629, 
    -0.05951115497, -0.02353665674, -0.01967923345, -0.10148651548, 
    -0.00480936518, -0.00098261723, -0.13970798195, -0.00286148145, 
    -0.05492902692, 0.10732815358, 0.11660744219, -0.02016620439
    ), Not.Resting = c(-0.77046287, 0.773856776, -2.593072768, 
    -2.837675606, -1.680828329, -0.947623773, -0.947623773, -2.607366431, 
    -0.637055341, -1.818396455, 2.170944974, -0.658126752, -0.808243774, 
    2.377766908, 2.111220276, -0.322326312, 2.218858946, 3.920878638, 
    -0.304945754, 1.038591535, 1.752268128, 0.907465624, 1.137774798, 
    -3.663486997, 2.350924346, 0.067293462, -1.898454393, -2.497647463, 
    -4.471716512, -1.465081244, -0.232806371, -3.043893581, -2.323908986, 
    1.437404886, 1.079056696, 1.110865131, 1.404724068, -1.706664294, 
    0.736746935, -0.005516985, 1.727170333, 1.685228831, 1.836016918, 
    0.46617392, 1.697173771, 1.057314221, 0.933704227, 0.482480775, 
    0.680713089, 0.090780703, 0.680713089, -0.982921741, -2.281900378, 
    0.97208909, 0.027767791, -0.1628815, -0.530221948, -0.385741863, 
    -0.972251823, 0.002267358, -1.134447998, 0.626424009, -0.722750217, 
    -0.382722075, -0.356550578, -1.851614124, -1.851614124, 1.731465143, 
    0.254319006, 2.043778341, -0.28991392, 1.386940871, 0.054207713, 
    0.594212936, 1.551821303, 3.100704184, 0.327263666, -1.055195336, 
    -1.134447998, 1.730726972), Hunting = c(-0.67708172, -0.58224128, 
    -0.11436177, -0.34830152, -0.84568695, -0.32933343, 0.35984044, 
    -0.3251183, 1.51478626, 0.11114773, 0.27975296, -0.89626852, 
    0.12379312, 0.66965255, 1.56536783, 0.56427428, -0.71291033, 
    -0.75927677, -0.75295407, -1.00164679, -1.03958296, 0.82139726, 
    -1.07541157, -1.0311527, -0.98900139, -1.06908888, -1.20186549, 
    0.58324237, -0.9700333, 0.22917139, 0.41042201, -1.11545531, 
    -0.19023412, 0.25446217, -0.05324237, 0.09007207, 1.21129685, 
    0.62539368, 1.32932051, 0.40199175, 0.44625062, 0.60221046, 
    0.33665722, -0.63493041, -0.282967, -0.32722587, -0.11646933, 
    -0.10171637, 0.13643851, -0.57802615, 0.05002833, -0.1607282, 
    -0.29139726, 0.13222338, -0.41152848, 0.68229794, -0.24292325, 
    -0.11646933, -0.21341734, -0.24292325, -0.24292325, 0.09007207, 
    -0.34197883, -0.30825778, -0.08696342, -0.8119659, 0.49683219, 
    -0.13754498, -0.4831857, 0.39988418, 0.90148474, 0.28396809, 
    1.05322945, 1.24923303, 0.47154141, 1.27873894, 0.05002833, 
    1.54218461, 0.74763247, 0.11747042), Not.Hunting = c(-0.097624192, 
    -0.160103675, -0.092996082, -0.234153433, -0.136963126, -0.15778962, 
    -0.15778962, -0.023574435, 0.00188017, -0.224897213, -0.109194467, 
    -0.069855533, -0.123078796, -0.111508522, -0.143905291, -0.099938247, 
    -0.118450687, 1.519900201, 0.177748344, 0.108326696, 0.652129604, 
    0.638245274, -0.072169588, 0.087500202, -0.18093017, -0.146219346, 
    -0.049029039, -0.125392851, -0.134649071, -0.060599313, -0.086053918, 
    -0.197128554, -0.083739863, -0.092996082, 0.844196163, 0.055103433, 
    1.971140911, -0.111508522, -0.224897213, -0.187872334, -0.160103675, 
    -0.194814499, -0.053657149, -0.206384774, 0.108326696, -0.164731785, 
    0.187004564, 0.025020719, 0.057417488, 0.434608441, 0.057417488, 
    0.073615872, -0.035144709, -0.051343094, -0.134649071, -0.185558279, 
    0.013450444, -0.134649071, -0.215640993, -0.185558279, -0.005061995, 
    -0.238781543, -0.099938247, -0.16704584, -0.208698829, 0.048161268, 
    0.048161268, -0.037458764, 0.16154996, 0.031962884, -0.102252302, 
    -0.123078796, -0.139277181, -0.208698829, -0.118450687, -0.072169588, 
    -0.044400929, -0.030516599, -0.132335016, -0.037458764), 
    Grooming = c(0.01081204879, -0.03398160805, 0.057108797, 
    -0.04063432116, -0.13084281035, -0.02997847693, 0.12732080268, 
    -0.1028170581, 0.08155320398, -0.17932134171, -0.14338902206, 
    -0.02058415581, -0.11528274705, -0.11764091337, 0.04389156236, 
    0.01399844913, -0.05755560242, 0.04711630687, 0.0158428036, 
    0.093485909, 0.09677967302, 0.02053612974, -0.03608286844, 
    0.07805238146, -9.686695e-05, -0.02285413055, -0.00424187149, 
    0.01446241356, 0.03187450017, 0.11323315542, -0.01171898422, 
    -0.06499053655, -0.07758659568, -0.07399758157, -0.11503350996, 
    0.02167111711, 0.01904454162, 0.05768779393, 0.05555202379, 
    -0.01031175326, -0.00458313459, 0.17430774591, 0.00481502094, 
    -0.00928412956, 0.09047589183, 0.08917985896, -0.05671203072, 
    -0.05333390954, 0.08541446168, 0.10140397965, -0.02509342995, 
    -0.0369877908, 0.04609635201, 0.06524159499, 0.0845977309, 
    -0.03239032508, -0.03208740616, 0.06264952925, 0.05241547086, 
    -0.03437271856, -0.03437271856, -0.06747523863, -0.01270059491, 
    0.10014629095, -0.02872845706, -0.00950652573, 0.04867308008, 
    0.02486518629, -0.05951115497, -0.02353665674, -0.01967923345, 
    -0.10148651548, -0.00480936518, -0.00098261723, -0.13970798195, 
    -0.00286148145, -0.05492902692, 0.10732815358, 0.11660744219, 
    -0.02016620439), Not.Grooming = c(-0.77046287, 0.773856776, 
    -2.593072768, -2.837675606, -1.680828329, -0.947623773, -0.947623773, 
    -2.607366431, -0.637055341, -1.818396455, 2.170944974, -0.658126752, 
    -0.808243774, 2.377766908, 2.111220276, -0.322326312, 2.218858946, 
    3.920878638, -0.304945754, 1.038591535, 1.752268128, 0.907465624, 
    1.137774798, -3.663486997, 2.350924346, 0.067293462, -1.898454393, 
    -2.497647463, -4.471716512, -1.465081244, -0.232806371, -3.043893581, 
    -2.323908986, 1.437404886, 1.079056696, 1.110865131, 1.404724068, 
    -1.706664294, 0.736746935, -0.005516985, 1.727170333, 1.685228831, 
    1.836016918, 0.46617392, 1.697173771, 1.057314221, 0.933704227, 
    0.482480775, 0.680713089, 0.090780703, 0.680713089, -0.982921741, 
    -2.281900378, 0.97208909, 0.027767791, -0.1628815, -0.530221948, 
    -0.385741863, -0.972251823, 0.002267358, -1.134447998, 0.626424009, 
    -0.722750217, -0.382722075, -0.356550578, -1.851614124, -1.851614124, 
    1.731465143, 0.254319006, 2.043778341, -0.28991392, 1.386940871, 
    0.054207713, 0.594212936, 1.551821303, 3.100704184, 0.327263666, 
    -1.055195336, -1.134447998, 1.730726972), Other = c(0.019502286, 
    -0.290451956, 0.359948884, 0.557840914, 0.117453376, 0.126645924, 
    0.126645924, 0.196486873, 0.152780228, 0.354469789, -0.261430968, 
    0.176448238, -0.007374708, -0.557848621, -0.213674557, -0.005819262, 
    -0.470070992, -0.786078864, 0.006063789, -0.27184265, -0.349418792, 
    -0.338096262, -0.165119403, 0.346566439, -0.344191931, 0.074321265, 
    0.179825379, 0.278407054, 0.593125727, 0.199177375, -0.058900625, 
    0.633875622, 0.428150308, -0.206023441, -0.436958199, -0.291839246, 
    -0.907641911, 0.448567295, -0.127186127, 0.024715134, -0.41634503, 
    -0.330697382, -0.469720666, -0.047494017, -0.301732446, -0.138901021, 
    0.098101379, -0.002063769, -0.02832419, 0.071630763, -0.02832419, 
    0.295110588, 0.347112947, -0.083577573, -0.036886152, 0.189045953, 
    0.467596992, 0.303378276, 0.218879697, 0.092005711, 0.27011134, 
    -0.012909856, 0.262292068, 0.107125772, 0.123422927, 0.299426602, 
    0.299426602, -0.326871824, -0.022088391, -0.428508341, -0.014675497, 
    -0.114462294, 0.087227267, -0.031519161, -0.159318008, -0.397875854, 
    0.101520559, 0.244481505, 0.529968994, -0.32661959)), .Names = c("Family", 
"Swimming", "Not.Swimming", "Running", "Not.Running", "Fighting", 
"Not.Fighting", "Resting", "Not.Resting", "Hunting", "Not.Hunting", 
"Grooming", "Not.Grooming", "Other"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

Comment: Please clean up this question. Here are the most obvious issues (but there might be more): 1) You post data called `mydat`, but your function call works with `behaviours`. Are they the same? 2) Your `structure()` misses a comma after `.Label = c("G8", "v4")` 3) The data contains fields `Not.Fighting` and `Not.Hunting`, but inside `summarySE()` you use `Not.fighting` and `Not.hunting`. 4) Your title and the example code in the last section mention `ggplot2`, but your problem happens before you use `ggplot2`.

Comment: 5) Even  after I corrected this issues (with guessing; I might be wrong...), I get many more error messages than those you mention.

Comment: Appart from all that: the help for `summarySE` says that `groupvars` is "a vector containing names of columns that contain grouping variables". It seems that you are using this function completely wrong. You can group by several variables, but only summarize one. You try to group by one variable (which is fine) and summarize several (which won't work).

Comment: I have corrected the typo's. The grouping variable is family - "G8" and "V4". This is a classification exercise and I would like to graphically show differences in variability between these families. I have switched the grouping variable to groupvar and predictors to measurevar, and another warning message was returned. At this point, I really do not understand these warning messages.

Comment: I tried to edit your question in something more useful. But there are still many problems that I cannot solve, for instance, the column `Resting` contains only 76 values instead of 80. Also, I get different error messages than you do. I know the answer to your question (that is, if I understand it correctly), but I will not answer as long as it is such a mess.

Comment: Hi Stibu, Thank you for your help. It is greatly appreciated. I re-copied the dataframe into the text and I believe that each column now contains 80 observations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the code variants that you posted won't work because they are using the function `summarySE()` wrongly:

- Version 1: You use `Family` as the measurement variable, which means that you ask the function to give you mean, standard deviation, etc. of `Family`.
- Version2: You correctly group by `Family`, but now  you supply many measurement variables. This does not work because `summarySE()` expects a single measurement variable. Try to imagine how the output table should  look with several measurement variables and you will notice that this won't be possible. You would have 13 columns for `sd`, 13 columns for `ci`, etc.

The problem with your data is that Swimming", "Not.Swimming", "Running", etc. are actually **values** not **variables**. (Explaining this in detail is too much for this answer; see [here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) if you need more information.) So, you need to convert your data into so-called **long format**:

```
library(tidyr)
long_behaviours <- gather(behaviours, variable, value, -Family)
long_behaviours[c(1, 120, 313, 730), ]
##     Family     variable       value
## 1       v4     Swimming -0.48055680
## 120     G8 Not.Swimming -0.05086028
## 313     G8  Not.Running -0.07139534
## 730     v4  Not.Hunting -0.22489721
```

As you can see from the few lines that I "randomly" picked from the resulting data frame, there is now a column that gives you the predictor and a single column with the numeric value. Now, you can use `value` as the measurement variable in `summarySE` and group by the other two:

```
library(Rmisc)
sum_behaviours <- summarySE(long_behaviours, measurevar =  "value",
                            groupvar = c("Family", "variable"), na.rm = TRUE)
head(sum_behaviours)
##   Family     variable  N        value         sd          se         ci
## 1     G8     Fighting 50  0.157977831 0.58253445 0.082382813 0.16555446
## 2     G8     Grooming 50  0.003784713 0.06611479 0.009350043 0.01878961
## 3     G8      Hunting 50  0.157977831 0.58253445 0.082382813 0.16555446
## 4     G8 Not.Fighting 50 -0.007098363 0.33806726 0.047809930 0.09607765
## 5     G8 Not.Grooming 50  0.202045803 1.30151612 0.184062175 0.36988679
## 6     G8  Not.Hunting 50 -0.007098363 0.33806726 0.047809930 0.09607765
```

You have now a table with mean, standard deviation, etc. for each Family and variable. This is the data you need to produce the plot according to the example from the R-Cookbook:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sum_behaviours, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Family)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - ci, ymax = value + ci),
                width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

A little side remark: I personally prefer a box plot to compare the distributions of various variables with each other:

```
ggplot(long_behaviours, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Family)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hiya Stibu. Words cannot express my gratitude for your help. I successfully produced the barplots with error bars; however, the box plots, which are definitely nicer, were not as successful. My biggest apologies, but I placed: (1) the code which I used to produce the long-format dataframe; (2) the code to summarise the data using the function summarySE(); (3) the code and a graphical representation of the bar plots; and (4) the code and a jpeg showing my failed attempt to produce box plots. Do you know how to fix the box plot problem? Thank you so much, I have learned a lot from you.

Comment: You are welcome; I'm glad it helped and that you learned something. Regarding the box plot: you are using the wrong data. There is not need to apply `summarySE()` first in that situation, because `geom_boxplot()` does all the necessary calculations itself. So you should use `long_behaviours` for the boxplot (not `long_behaviours1`).

Comment: Great! Success with the boxplots! This has been a great interactive experience. Take care and Thank you again from a very happy person